# TYPO3 2-level menu generating

Tags: typo3, typoscript

So I have pages set like this

```
Page(uid=63)
    subpage1
         subpage1-item1
         subpage1-item2
    supgage2
         subpage2-item1
         subpage2-item2
```

And I have following typoscript:

```
lib.hotelrooms = HMENU
lib.hotelrooms.wrap = <a href="#">Indoor</a><ul> | </ul>
lib.hotelrooms {
    special = directory
    special.value = 63
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO.doNotLinkIt = 1
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li><a href="#">|</a></li>           
    }
   2 < .1
   2.wrap = <ul class="level_2">|</ul>

}
```

the output I get is something like

```
<ul>
    <li>
      Subpage1
       <ul>
           <li>subpage1-item1</li>
            <li>subpage1-item2</li>
       </ul>
     </li>

     <li>
      Subpage2
     </li>
</ul>
```

instead of:

```
<ul>
    <li>
      Subpage1
       <ul>
           <li>subpage1-item1</li>
           <li>subpage1-item2</li>
       </ul>
     </li>

     <li>
      Subpage2
        <ul>
           <li>subpage2-item1</li>
           <li>subpage2-item2</li>
       </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, TYPO3 only expands the subpages of the current page. To expand all subpages, set

```
1 {
  expAll = 1
}
```